# how to read image and document using phonegap?

Tags: android, image, cordova

I need to read document and image using phonegap.

```
But i can read image only using window.open(url); but it's not working document.
And i can read document only using window.open(https://docs.google.com/viewer?url="");

but i need to read image and document using same url or api in phonegap.
if any possible for do this?
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use this html5lightbox will work in both ios and android. It supports images, Flash SWF files, YouTube, Vimeo and local mp4, m4v, flv, ogg, ogv and webm videos, works on Windows, Linux, Mac, iPhone, iPad, Android, Windows Phone and all modern web browsers

http://html5box.com/html5lightbox/

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap cannot open document files by default. you have to install plugins to add these feature to it. for example you can use FileOpener plugin to open some common file extensions such as PDF, WORD, EXCEL, JPG, GIF, POWERPOINT, VIDEOS, MUSIC etc.

https://github.com/frankk994/phonegapFileOpener

https://github.com/pwlin/cordova-plugin-file-opener